# Sencha CMD - defining meta class definition

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a workspace project that includes an ExtJS app, Touch app, and a set of files that are shared between the two projects set up like this

```
WorkspaceFolder
    ExtJSAppFolder
    TouchAppFolder
    SharedCodeFolder
```

I have the `SharedCodeFolder` referenced in the bootstrap loader and the ExtJS/Touch applications load in the browser fine

```
bootstrap.js

Ext.Loader.addClassPathMappings({
  "ExtJSApp": "app",
  "Ext": "../ext/src",
  "Ext.rtl.EventObjectImpl": "../ext/src/rtl/EventObject.js",  
  'SharedCode': '../SharedCodeFolder/'
});
```

but when I try to use Sencha Cmd to build, it's giving me this error

```
[ERR] failed to find meta class definition for name 
      ExtJSApp.store.SharedCode.store.StoreFile
```

How do I tell Sencha Cmd to not append the ExtJS app namespace to the name of the SharedCode file?  It should be looking for

```
SharedCode.store.StoreFile
```

not

```
ExtJSApp.store.SharedCode.store.StoreFile
```

Answer (score -2):

You can add the SharedCodeFolder path to your workspace.classpath in the WorkspaceFolder/.sencha/workspace/sencha.cfg file:

```
workspace.classpath=${workspace.dir}/SharedCodeFolder
```

See here for more info:
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-2/#!/guide/command_workspace-section-7

Comment: yea, I've already done that.  I don't think Cmd is having a problem finding the files, but its appending the namespace and I don't know how to tell it not to.